# Securing MySQL backup process

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, percona

I'm running my MySQL backups through cron scheduled every night, but the thing is in cron the username and password is given for it run, is there any other way I can securely run the backups? where I can credentials remain secure only to the DBAs and not to anyone else? Btw, I use percona server. But I use mysqldump for backups, just that it has to be secure.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by secure? There must be defined threats so you can measure how your backups are protected against them.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `.my.cnf` file in your home directory then store the user/password info on the `[mysqldump]` section.

`vi ~/.my.cnf`

```
[mysqldump]
user = dump_user
password = dump_password
```

Then, with your mysqldump command, use the `--defaults-extra-file` option to specify explicitly your conf file has your are in crontab.

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump --defaults-extra-file=/home/max/.my.cnf  --single-transaction  --all-databases >/space/mydump.sql
```

Max.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [mysqldump-secure](http://mysqldump-secure.org) which acts as a wrapper around `mysqldump` and will take care about password security (via a `defaults-extra-file`) and also offers your to encrypt your mysql databases via asymmetric encryption.

Optional support for Nagios monitoring is also included and can be turned on via the config file.